# Integration in polar coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$ - is this a Lebesgue integral?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

In my PDE class, we were given the following formula: if $f$ is an integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)dx=\int_0^\infty r^{n-1}\int_{S^{n-1}} f(ry)d\sigma(y)dr.$$
So, on $S^{n-1}$ we are using a surface measure (I understood that it actually is the $n-1$ dimensional Hausdorff measure). However, in the lecture notes this is written as $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)dx=\int_0^\infty r^{n-1}\int_{S^{n-1}} f(ry)dydr$$ and the comments before the formula hint towards the fact that the integral on $S^{n-1}$ is just the usual integral with respect to the $n-1$ dimensional Lebesgue measure. Which one of these is correct? Considering [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954558/polar-coordinates-in-mathbb-rn) topic, I believe that indeed we just have to deal with a regular Lebesgue integral, but I am not really sure.

Comment: Think about what would happen when $n=2$ and $n=3$

Comment: @whoisit it looks like it is just the usual Lebesgue integral?

Comment: What is “the usual Lebesgue integral” on a submanifold (say a sphere) of $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I was thinking about simply integrating with respect to the $n-1$ dimensional Lebesgue measure., but now that I think of it it sounds kind of wrong.

Comment: I do not know what that means. You need to use an induced volume form (which uses differential forms and the Riemannian structure) or the appropriate Hausdorff measure.

Comment: @TedShifrin ok, as far as I can tell we are using the Hausdorff measure in my course. What I don't actually understand is how I compute such an integral, i.e. how do I compute the integral $\int_{S^{n-1}}f(ry)d\sigma(y)$ in my first equation? I suppose that one treats this as the surface integrals we encounter in calculus, right?

Comment: Yes, but higher dimensional. A rigorous treatment requires differential forms. But I suspect you don’t have to do much explicit computation with the spherical integral. You just need to conceptualize it — e.g., with the mean value property of harmonic functions.

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks, now I get it. I was afraid that I must be able to compute such things and that sounded really daunting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d\sigma(y)$ is surface measure on $S^{n - 1}$ (surface measure can be defined on any smooth surface). If $\phi : O \subset \mathbb{R}^{n - 1} \to U$ parameterizes an open subset $U$ of $S^{n - 1}$ and $f : S^{n - 1} \to \mathbb{R}$ is compactly supported in $U$, then $\int_{S^{n - 1}} f(y)\,d\sigma(y) = \int_{O}f(\phi(x))\sqrt{\det D\phi(x)^TD\phi(x)}\,dx$. You can integrate a general function by using a partition of unity, but in practice you just use enough disjoint parameterizations to cover $S^{n - 1}$ up to measure $0$ and add the integrals for each parameterization.